# I'm not able to get summary for one of the columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I have a data-frame which is df.

```
    id       time  internet lat lng
103  1 1385913600 14.057844   1   0
247  2 1385913600 14.062213   2   0
391  3 1385913600 14.066863   3   0
535  4 1385913600 14.045190   4   0
679  5 1385913600 12.772210   5   0
823 10 1385913600  8.101804  10   0
```

I added a new column and put values of all of them 0 by using one of the below methods:

```
df["cluster"] <- 0
df$cluster <- 0
```

And then by using my algorithm I changed value of each df$cluster which you can see the method I used to change value of df$cluster:

```
clusternumber <- clusternumber + 1
df$cluster[df$id == minid] <- clusternumber
```

At the end I got the result I'm looking but I've faced with a new problem. When I'm trying to get summary of my result I'm getting strange result.

```
> summary(df)
       id           internet            lat              lng            cluster    
 Min.   :    1   Min.   :   0.00   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   :  0.00   1      : 121  
 1st Qu.: 2500   1st Qu.:  15.57   1st Qu.: 25.25   1st Qu.: 25.00   2      : 121  
 Median : 5000   Median :  36.09   Median : 51.00   Median : 49.50   3      : 121  
 Mean   : 5000   Mean   :  75.73   Mean   : 50.50   Mean   : 49.51   4      : 121  
 3rd Qu.: 7501   3rd Qu.:  78.88   3rd Qu.: 75.75   3rd Qu.: 75.00   9      : 121  
 Max.   :10000   Max.   :6663.23   Max.   :100.00   Max.   :100.00   15     : 121  
                                                                     (Other):9272
```

I'm looking to know how do I have to make a new column or change value of a column because now I'm getting this:

```
> summary(df$cluster)
      1       2       3       4       9      15      16      17      34      52      85     147       8       6       7      36 
    121     121    other(2727)
```

Comment: It seems like your `cluster` column is `factor`, so `summary` reports the number of each level.

Comment: @ycw exactly sometimes I got an error and it showed me that cluster column is factor, however, it's not factor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your `summary` function clearly shows that the `cluster` column is `factor`. Below is a simple example.

```
# Create an example data frame
dat <- data.frame(Col_f = c("1.1", "1.1", "2.1", "2.1", "3.1", "3.1", 
                            "4.1", "4.1", "4.1"),
                  Col_n = c(1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1))

# Check the structure of the data frame
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Col_f: Factor w/ 4 levels "1.1","2.1","3.1",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
# $ Col_n: num  1.1 1.1 2.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 4.1

# Use summary
summary(dat)
#   Col_f       Col_n      
# 1.1:2   Min.   :1.100  
# 2.1:2   1st Qu.:2.100  
# 3.1:2   Median :3.100  
# 4.1:3   Mean   :2.767  
#         3rd Qu.:4.100  
#         Max.   :4.100
```

Notice that in `Col_f` `summary` function simply reports the number in each level.

To convert the `factor` to `numeric`, You may want to convert the column to `character` first, then convert to numeric. Here is an example.

```
# Convert the column of factor to numeric
dat$Col_fn <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$Col_f))
```

Notice that `Col_fn` is the same as `Col_n`.

```
# Call str again
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Col_f : Factor w/ 4 levels "1.1","2.1","3.1",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
# $ Col_n : num  1.1 1.1 2.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 4.1
# $ Col_fn: num  1.1 1.1 2.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 4.1
```

If you directly convert `factor` to numeric, it will be based on the level. Here is an example.

```
# Convert the column of factor to numeric
dat$Col_ff <- as.numeric(dat$Col_f)

# Use str again
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Col_f : Factor w/ 4 levels "1.1","2.1","3.1",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
# $ Col_n : num  1.1 1.1 2.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 4.1
# $ Col_fn: num  1.1 1.1 2.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 4.1
# $ Col_ff: num  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
```

Notice that col_ff are integers ranging from `1` to `4` because those were the level numbers.

Comment: Thank you, It did work. I just convert the column of factor to numeric.